# How to make ubuntu VM accessible from Internet

Tags: networking, network-bridge, virtualbox-networking

My host machine (windows) is accessible from internet.
My guest VM (which is Ubuntu 17 with static ip) is accessible from the host.
I want my ubuntu guest to be accessible from internet.
I run vmware with both bridged and NAT interfaces.

Where should I look for my answer?
Ubuntu config? Windows rounting? Vmware?

Answer (score 2):

All of the above.

- On the Ubuntu system, there must be a *service* listening on an *open port*
- On the VM, the interface must either be bridged to your LAN, or (if it is NAT'ed), the port on which the service is listening must be forwarded across the NAT
- On your router, the port must be forwarded from the LAN side to the WAN (public) side.

In addition, your ISP must not block the chosen WAN port.